# What is a zero sized array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This code prints address of some location and zero. This address is of which location ? 
I have similar confusion when no argument is passed in variable argument method , then still  p points to an array of size zero .

```
public class zero 
{
static void abc (int ... p )  // variable number of arguments .
{
System.out.println(p.length);  
}

public static void main (String qwe[] )    
{
int x[] =new int [0] ;    

System.out.println(x);

abc () ;

}

}
```

Comment: It's not an address, it's the object's [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Comment: It prints `0` and a `hashCode` (because that is what `toString` in `Object` returns). `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));` will print the "value" of an empty array.

Comment: empty array ? is there any array ?

Comment: @steve You declared it, so yes, there is an array which contains 0 elements (an empty array)

Comment: An array of size zero is _still a new object._  You can have two of them and they won't be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

1st: It's not an adress, it's the array's `hash code`

2nd: No matter if you have an array of 0 elements as parameter or p as array with 0 element, you always get 0 as length.